# xargs - if condition and echo {}

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, echo, xargs

I have some files that contain a particular strings. What I want to do is, search a location for the file; if the file exists grep for the pattern; if true, do something.

```
find -iname file.xxx| xargs -I {} if grep -Fq "string" {} ; then echo {} ; fi
```

The problems are:

- `xargs` is not working with the if statement.
- `echo {}` does not give the file name, instead gives `{}`.

How do I fix these?

Comment: Why not have `find` run `grep` itself?

Comment: do something on file or grepped line?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try to run the command through a shell like this:

```
$ find -iname file.xxx |
> xargs -I {} bash -c 'if grep -Fq "string" {} ; then echo {} ; fi'
```

where the original command has been surrounded by quotes and `bash -c`.

Comment: `find` + `xargs` for parallel. But if you try to do some complex thing inside `xargs`, it becomes real ugly. :/

Answer (score 11):

Wrap the if-statement in a call to sh:

```
find -iname file.xxx | xargs -I {} sh -c 'grep -Fq "string" {} && { echo {}; }'
```

Use a while-loop instead of xargs

```
find -iname file.xxx | while read -r file; do
  if grep -Fq "$file"; then
    # do something
    echo "$file"
  fi
done
```

I assume you want to do more than echo the filename. If that's all you're trying to do, use grep's  `-l` option:

```
find -iname file.xxx | xargs grep -Fl "string"
```

Answer (score 2):

First, `if` is a bash-command and no executable program. `xargs` on the other hand needs a distinct program.

Second, the `;` characters are probably splitting the your command. You would have to escape them in order to get them throu to xargs.

To avoid all this I suggest the following:

```
for i in `find -iname file.xxx` ; do grep -Fq "string" $i && echo $i ; done
```

Comment: In general, using a for-loop is not recommended due to the way it word-splits the output of find -- filenames with spaces will be split. Better to use a while-loop to read the filenames.